# Как отправить FormData AJAX-запросом без Jquery, т.е. через чистый JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Имеется следующий код:
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Photo Service</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
    <script src="scripts/script.js" defer></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" defer integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="scripts/vue.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="modal_error modal"></div>
        <form method="POST" id='form_upload' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <div class="images_wrapper">
                <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/1.png">
            </div>
            <input onchange="showImages()" accept="image/png,image/jpg,image/jpeg" multiple type="file" name="file[]" id="input" class="input">
            <label for="input" name='image' class="input_label">+</label>
            <input type='submit' class="button-standart " value='Загрузить' type="submit"></input>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript

```
function logFiles() {
    console.log(document.getElementById('input').files);
}
let form = document.getElementById('form_upload');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        let formData = new FormData(form);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST'.toUpperCase(), // тип запроса
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/photo', // куда будем отправлять, можно явно указать
            data: formData, // данные, которые передаем
            cache: false, // кэш и прочие настройки писать именно так (для файлов)
            // (связано это с кодировкой и всякой лабудой)
            contentType: false, // нужно указать тип контента false для картинки(файла)
            processData: false, // для передачи картинки(файла) нужно false 
            success: function(data) { // в случае успешного завершения
                console.log("Завершилось успешно"); // выведем в консоли успех 
                console.log(data); // и что в ответе получили, если там что-то есть
            },
            error: function(exception) { // в случае провала
                console.log("Завершилось с ошибкой"); // сообщение об ошибке
                showError(exception.statusText);
            },
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer qfwqwfqwfqwwqfw'
            },
        });
    })


function setHashtags(el) {
    console.log('settingHash');
    let hashtagsBlock = el.nextSibling.nextSibling;
    let hashtags = el.value.split(/\||\s/);

    hashtagsBlock.innerHTML = '';
    console.log(hashtags);
    hashtags.forEach(hashtag => {
        if (hashtag != '') hashtagsBlock.innerHTML += '<div class = "hashtag">' + hashtag + '</div>';
    });
    el.value = hashtags.join('|');
    console.log(hashtagsBlock);
}
let images = [];

function showImages() {
    for (let i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
        images.push(input.files[i]);
    }
    let fileReader = [];
    document.querySelector('.images_wrapper ').innerHTML = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        image = images[i];
        fileReader[i] = new FileReader();
        fileReader[i].readAsDataURL(image);
        document.querySelector('.images_wrapper ').innerHTML += `
        <div class="image_block">
                    <img id='image` + i + `' src="" alt="" class="image">
                    <input autocomplete="off" required="true" placeholder="Name" type="text" name="name[]" id="input_name" class="input_name input-standart">
                    <input autocomplete="off" required="true" placeholder="Hashtags" oninput="setHashtags(this)" type="text" name="hashtags[]" id="input_hastags" class="input_hastags input-standart">
                    <div class="hashtags_wrapper">
                    </div>
                </div>
         `;
        fileReader[i].addEventListener('load', function() {
            document.getElementById('image' + i).src = fileReader[i].result;
        });
    }
}


function showError(text) {
    document.querySelector('.modal_error').innerHTML = text;
    document.querySelector('.modal_error').classList.add('show');
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.querySelector('.modal_error').classList.remove('show');
    }, 2000)
}
```

В коде JavaScript есть события отправки формы, в которой с помощью Jquery отправляется AJAX-запрос с FormData(names[],hashtags[],file[]). Как отправить этот же AJAX-запрос без Jquery, а на чистом JavaScript.

т.е просто нужно заменить запрос Jquery на JavaScript

(еще раз повторю, отправляется FormData).

Заранее спасибо, буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю как-то так можно отправить

при высылке через `fetch` `formData = new FormData(form)`, `Content-Type` в `headers` автоматом установится @Grundy

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/photo', {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer qfwqwfqwfqwwqfw'      
    },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *client
    body: formData // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
})
.then(
    response => return response.json())
.then(
    data => {
      console.log("Завершилось успешно"); // выведем в консоли успех 
      console.log(data); // и что в ответе получили, если там что-то есть
      return response.json();
})
.catch(function(exception) {
      console.log("Завершилось с ошибкой"); // сообщение об ошибке
      showError(exception.statusText);
});
```